# cannot open database - requested by the login - why can't I connect to my DB?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

I'm trying to insert some data into my DB *(**Microsoft SQL Server**)*

My connection does not open and I get this message:

> Cannot open database \"[Sales and Inventory System]\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'Mostafa-PC\Mostafa'.

here is my code:

```
public void InsertProduct(List<string> _myName, 
                      List<int> _myAmount, 
                      List<int> _myPrice, string _date)
{
string connectionString = @"Data Source=MOSTAFA-PC;Initial Catalog=[Sales and Inventory System];Integrated Security=True";
string query = @"INSERT INTO dbo.product(Name, Amount, Price, [date]) 
                             VALUES(@Name, @Amount, @Price, @Date);";

using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con))
{

    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Int);
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(_date);

    Cmd.Connection = Con;
    Con.Open();

    int recordsToAdd = _myName.Count();
    for(int x = 0; x < recordsToAdd; x++)
    {
        Cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = _myName[x];
        Cmd.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = _myAmount[x];
        Cmd.Parameters["@Price"].Value = _myPrice[x];
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I've done everything and I've searched everywhere. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What error message do you get? Have you tried connecting the instance in SSMS? Have you checked credential running the code has access?

Comment: why you have not declared `User ID=xyz;Password=xyz;` in connection string?

Comment: OR else you could set connection string in web.config and then try to access like this `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"]` from code side.

Comment: @KenYao Question edited

Comment: @curiousguy i just copied conection string

Comment: So you have copied from web.config? and then paste here in code? also have you checked by declaring userid and password?

Comment: you should check this first - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/ - as This problem occurs because the user account that you used to access database or that tries to execute query does not have sufficient permissions.

Comment: @curiousguy i copied it from app.comfig and it didnt work

Comment: so it was working before or not from app.config?

Comment: @curiousguy no it didnt work at all

Comment: @curiousguy i did what it said in that site and it didnt work for me

Comment: Have you checked permission?

Comment: @curiousguy that site didnt say any thing about  permissions and I did every steps in the site but when i want to connect same error occours

Comment: Have you tried connecting the instance in SSMS?

Comment: @curiousguy thanks to you it was fixed,can you write(or copy youre comments in an anwser) so i can accept it as a Compelete Awnser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to check below things to solve your error.

**1.** *Check permission.* User must have access to this `Database`. **`Most Important One`**

**2.** Also, It would be better to access  `App.config key` to code side. So declare connection string in `app.config` and try to set like below.

```
string connectionstring = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["keyname"]
```

**3.** You also need to try connecting the instance in `SSMS` and It should not be failed.

This [Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/) can be helpful to you for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The error is definitely permission related. 
Check permission of the account on the instance and DB. 
And make sure the DB really exists on the server. Sometimes, it complains about permission but DB doesn't even exist.